# JFormDesigner - how to adjust column alignment in two different panels

Tags: java, user-interface, jform-designer

I have a small issue with jfd. On the main pain there are two different panes. Each of them has the same number of columns. I'd like this columns to be align in the same way so that if the user looks at the dialog data are seen in smooth straight columns although they are in two (ore more) different panes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you asking this question?
[Align Swing Components across Panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761270/align-swing-components-across-panels)